# I'm trying to get specific results from my Lucky Sevens program, but I'm not sure where to go from here

Tags: python, loops, parameters

I'm trying to calculate the number of rolls it takes to go broke, and the amount of rolls that would have left you with the most money. The program is split into several functions outside of main (not my choice) so that makes it more difficult for me.

I'm very new to python, and this is an exercise for school. I'm just not really sure where to go from here, and I realize I'm probably doing some of this wrong. Here's the code I have so far:

```
import random

def displayHeader(funds):
    print ("--------------------------")
    print ("--------------------------")
    print ("-      Lucky Sevens      -")
    print ("--------------------------")
    print ("--------------------------")
    funds = int(input("How many dollars do you have? "))

def rollDie(newFunds): 
#this function is supposed to simulate the roll of two die and return results
    while funds > 0:
        diceRoll = random.randint(1,6)
        totalRoll = (diceRoll + diceRoll)
        if totalRoll == 7:
            funds = funds + 4
        else:
            funds = funds - 1
    if funds == 0:
        newFunds = funds

def displayResults(): 
#this function is supposed to display the final results. 
#the number of rolls, the number of rolls you should have stopped at, and the max amount of money you would have had.

def main():
#everything gathered from the last function would be printed here.   

main()
```

Comment: Because this is an homework learn how functions return values and how to call functions, looks to me you just learned how to ask at stackoverflow gg

Comment: I always wonder: if it's an assignment from school and you have no idea where to start, why don't you talk to your classmates? I'm not even sure where to begin helping because the question "where to start" is really hard (not to say: impossible) to answer for me using StackOverflow. It would be much easier face to face.

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

maxmoney = []
minmoney = []

def displayHeader():
    print ("--------------------------")
    print ("--------------------------")
    print ("-      Lucky Sevens      -")
    print ("--------------------------")
    print ("--------------------------")
    funds = int(input("How many dollars do you have? "))
    return funds

        

def rollDie(): 
    #this function is supposed to simulate the roll of two die and return results
    funds = displayHeader()
    while funds > 0:
        diceRoll1 = random.randint(1,6)
        diceRoll2 = random.randint(1,6)
        totalRoll = (diceRoll1 + diceRoll2)
        if totalRoll == 7:
            funds = funds + 4
            maxmoney.append(funds)
        else:
            funds = funds - 1
            minmoney.append(funds)


def displayResults(): 
    #this function is supposed to display the final results. 
    #the number of rolls, the number of rolls you should have stopped at, and the max amount of money you would have had.
    rollDie()
    numOfRolls = len(maxmoney) + len(minmoney)
    numOfRolls2Stop = (len(maxmoney) - 1 - maxmoney[::-1].index(max(maxmoney))) + (len(minmoney) - 1 - minmoney[::-1].index(max(maxmoney)-1)) + 1 if maxmoney and minmoney else 0
    maxAmount = max(maxmoney) if maxmoney else 0
    return numOfRolls, numOfRolls2Stop, maxAmount

def main():
    #everything gathered from the last function would be printed here. 
    a, b, c = displayResults()
    print('The number of total rolls is : ' + str(a))
    print("The number of rolls you should've stopped at is: " + str(b))
    print("The maximun amount of money you would've had is: $" + str(c))
  

main()
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your program use variables that can only be accessed in certain scopes, so I think that the most recommended thing is that you use a **class**.

`displayHeader` input method it could stop the execution of the program since if you do not introduce a numerical value it will **raises** an exception called **`ValueError`**, if this does not help you much, I advise you to read the code carefully and add missing variables such as the input amount and the final amount and others...

```
class rollDiceGame():
     def __init__(self): 
          self.funds = 0
          self.diceRollCount = 0
     
    def displayHeader(self):
        print ("--------------------------")
        print ("--------------------------")
        print ("-      Lucky Sevens      -")
        print ("--------------------------")
        print ("--------------------------")
        self.funds = int(input("How many dollars do you have? ")) 

    def rollDice(self):
        while self.funds > 0:
            diceRoll = random.randint(1,6)
            totalRoll = (diceRoll + diceRoll)
            self.diceRollCount += 1
            if totalRoll == 7:
                self.funds += 4
            else:
                self.funds -= 1

     def displayResult(self):
         print('Roll count %d' % (self.diceRollCount))
         print('Current funds %d' % (self.funds))

def main():
    test = RollDiceGame()
    test.displayHeader()
    test.rollDice()
    test.displayResult()

main()
```